# minimum healthy ratio on a nutrition label: Unsaturated/Saturated fat?

Tags: nutrition, cholesterol, fatty-acids, ldl, hdl

This is not a question about overall or daily nutrition intakes (ex: not asking percentage of daily fat or calories).  Instead, I'm asking about assessing an ***individual nutrition label***: To help decide whether or not to eat that particular food.

**On a ***nutrition label***, is there a good minimum ratio of Unsaturated to Saturated fat (to at least outweigh the Bad of the Saturated)?**

- (ex:  2g Unsaturated fat to 1g Saturated fat [on a label] = 2 / 1 = 2)

Since Unsaturated fat is "Good" (including because it [helps reduce "Bad" LDL cholesterol](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/cholesterol/hdl-good-ldl-bad-cholesterol-and-triglycerides)), **I wonder if there is a minimum ratio [where anything above is additionally good], where the "Good" of the Unsaturated fat outweighs [or breaks even with] the "Bad" of the Saturated.**  Further below here are references underlying my question (and working knowledge that precedes it) on Unsaturated/Saturated fat, HDL/LDL cholesterol, & the Good/Bad of them.

fwiw, here are some "example" ratios with theories I came up with (these might not be true at all):

- [>=] 1 Unsaturated / 1 Saturated

  - so that at worst, the "Good" quantity (not necessarily benefit) is not outweighed by the "Bad"
- [>=] 4 / 1

  - because, ["Only one-third to one-fourth of blood cholesterol is carried by HDL"](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/cholesterol/hdl-good-ldl-bad-cholesterol-and-triglycerides)
- [>=] 2.25 / 1

  - because [this](https://healthmatters.io/understand-blood-test-results/unsaturatedsaturated-ratio#:%7E:text=Optimal%20Result%3A%202.25%20%2D%2010%20Ratio,Interpret%20your%20laboratory%20results%20now.&text=%2D%2D%20Increasing%20polyunsaturated%20(PUFA)%20intake,and%20decreases%20heart%20disease%20risk.) page says so (although that site appears commercial, so maybe it is not reliable)

---

- [LDL is "Bad" cholesterol - HDL is "Good"](https://www.cdc.gov/cholesterol/ldl_hdl.htm#:%7E:text=High%20levels%20of%20LDL%20cholesterol,flushes%20it%20from%20the%20body.)

  - ["HDL carries LDL (bad) cholesterol away"](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/cholesterol/hdl-good-ldl-bad-cholesterol-and-triglycerides)
- ["saturated and trans fats causes your body to produce even more LDL"](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/cholesterol/prevention-and-treatment-of-high-cholesterol-hyperlipidemia/the-skinny-on-fats)
- ["To raise your HDL level... eat unsaturated fats"](https://medlineplus.gov/hdlthegoodcholesterol.html)

(Related, it also looks like it is important to keep something like [this](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/what-should-you-eat/fats-and-cholesterol/types-of-fat/) in mind):

> Cutting back on saturated fat will likely have no benefit, however, if people replace saturated fat with refined carbohydrates. Eating refined carbohydrates in place of saturated fat does lower “bad” LDL cholesterol, but it also lowers the “good” HDL cholesterol and increases triglycerides. The net effect is as bad for the heart as eating too much saturated fat.